# How to slice a sentence like this in Python?

Tags: python, nlp

Assuming that I have a sentence like "The food is not delicious.".

If I use traditional method to slice this sentence into words, the result may be as follows:

```
    "The/food/is/not/delicious/"
```

but I want to slice the sentence as following:

```
    "The/food/is/not delicious/"
```

The question is how to realize it in Python? Thanks a lot!


I am so sorry for decribing the quesition too breif before, in the sentence "The food is not delicious", **"not delicious"** is a attibute of the **"food"**, so when I slice this sentence I want to let the word group "not delicious" go to a single slot. Similarly, assuming I have another sentence like this:

```
    "Mr.Lee is a nice person."
```

Now, **"nice"** is a attribute of **person**, so the slicing result is:

```
    "Mr.Lee/is/a/nice/person"
```

But if I change the sentence to:

```
    "Mr.Lee is not a nice person."
```

I wonder if it's possible to slice the sentence as:

```
    "Mr.Lee/is/a/not nice/person"
```

I think the most difficult problem is to find out which word is decorated by a negative word.


*Maybe this question is stupid enough, but thanks a lot anyway!*

Comment: Could you explain what your rule is for when not to split? At the moment it looks like you either want to keep the last two words together. Or possibly keep the word following "not"?

Comment: Are you trying to parse the sentence based on the rules of English grammar?

Comment: No, I think he is looking for some kind of built-in sentiment split.

Answer (score 0):

In the very specific case of your example, this code should work.
Please detail your question if it does not help you.

```
import re
sentence = "The food is not delicious"
sentence = sentence.replace(' ', '/').replace('/not/', '/not ')
```